# Can not find error in java script "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Tags: javascript, html

Give this code 10 seconds and it'll give the following error:

> {
> "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",
> "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
> "lineno": 1,
> "colno": 28
> }

It seems to be pointing to something in a library, but it completely stops my code from running. I want this code to check whether my server is up and then see if there have been any changes to a display library, if there have been then it updates the page.

```js
function checkServerStatus2(lastUpdated, display_id) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.onload = function() {
    //server reachable
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "/checkLinks/" + display_id, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 && this.statusText == 'OK') {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        var displayLastUpdated = json.lastUpdated;
        if (displayLastUpdated > lastUpdated) {
          //refresh page if server has been updated
          alert("RELOADING");
          location.reload(1);
        }
        //else do nothing
        alert("no updates");
      }
      //else server didn't respond do nothing
      alert("server sent picture but not json");
    };
    xhttp.send();
    img.onerror = function() {
      //server unreachable
      alert('Server Down!');
    };
    //image to pull to check if server is reachable
    img.src = "/static/img/aol.png?t=" + Date.now();
  };
}

//Included old function that works, just trying to get it to check a date with my server
function checkServerStatus() {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.onload = function() {
    //alert("Yay");
  };
  img.onerror = function() {
    //server unreachable
    alert('Server Down!');
  };
  //image to pull to check if server is reachable
  img.src = "/static/img/aol.png?t=" + Date.now();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!--Kill Favicon request -->
  <link rel="icon" href="data:,">

  <title>Home: Home</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!--My styles sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles.css">
  <!-- My Java Scripts -->
  <script src="/static/js/moment.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Script from server for moment text generator -->
  <script src="/static/scripts.js"></script>
</head>




<script>
  var myVar = setInterval("checkServerStatus2(2020-08-22 20:24:53.520739, 13)", 10 * 1000);
</script>

<div class="full-screen-scroller" style="width: 400px;" background-color: powderblue;>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">



      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>




      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>




      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>



    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">



      <div class="item active">
        <img style="width: 100%; max-height: 400px;" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/r1fDuPIcs18d2/giphy-downsized-large.gif" alt="Snoop Dog!">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Snoop Dog!</h3>
        </div>
      </div>




      <div class="item">
        <img style="width: 100%; max-height: 400px;" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/WZ5tDWAQrUeuk/giphy.gif" alt="Wowzers!">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Wowzers!</h3>
        </div>
      </div>




      <div class="item">
        <img style="width: 100%; max-height: 400px;" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/WZ5tDWAQrUeuk/giphy.gif" alt="wowzers2">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>wowzers2</h3>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I ran your code in jsfiddle and it seems to work. I made no changes to it.

https://jsfiddle.net/p5so7u9v/

Comment: Once the time setInterval runs you will see the error. It runs every 10seconds.

Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 1,
  "colno": 28
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely this:

```js
"checkServerStatus2(2020-08-22 20:24:53.520739, 13)"
```

This is invoking a function as a string, but notice the arguments inside the function call. If we were to omit the outer quotes, we'd get this:

```js
checkServerStatus2(2020-08-22 20:24:53.520739, 13)
```

The first argument is invalid. JavaScript assumes that the `2020-08-22` part is an arithmetic expression and should be a single argument that is then separated by a space with some other expression. Thus, JavaScript assumes you meant to place a closing paren to complete the function call, i.e. it thinks you intended to do `checkServerStatus2(2020-08-22)`. This is where the error is coming from.

To fix this, surround the first argument in quotes (I'll use single quotes for simplicity here):

```js
"checkServerStatus2('2020-08-22 20:24:53.520739', 13)"
```

The full solution would then look like this:

```js
function checkServerStatus2(lastUpdated, display_id) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.onload = function() {
    //server reachable
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "/checkLinks/" + display_id, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 && this.statusText == 'OK') {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        var displayLastUpdated = json.lastUpdated;
        if (displayLastUpdated > lastUpdated) {
          //refresh page if server has been updated
          alert("RELOADING");
          location.reload(1);
        }
        //else do nothing
        alert("no updates");
      }
      //else server didn't respond do nothing
      alert("server sent picture but not json");
    };
    xhttp.send();
    img.onerror = function() {
      //server unreachable
      alert('Server Down!');
    };
    //image to pull to check if server is reachable
    img.src = "/static/img/aol.png?t=" + Date.now();
  };
}

//Included old function that works, just trying to get it to check a date with my server
function checkServerStatus() {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.onload = function() {
    //alert("Yay");
  };
  img.onerror = function() {
    //server unreachable
    alert('Server Down!');
  };
  //image to pull to check if server is reachable
  img.src = "/static/img/aol.png?t=" + Date.now();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!--Kill Favicon request -->
  <link rel="icon" href="data:,">

  <title>Home: Home</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!--My styles sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles.css">
  <!-- My Java Scripts -->
  <script src="/static/js/moment.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Script from server for moment text generator -->
  <script src="/static/scripts.js"></script>
</head>




<script>
  var myVar = setInterval("checkServerStatus2('2020-08-22 20:24:53.520739', 13)", 10 * 1000);
</script>

<div class="full-screen-scroller" style="width: 400px;" background-color: powderblue;>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">



      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>




      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>




      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>



    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">



      <div class="item active">
        <img style="width: 100%; max-height: 400px;" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/r1fDuPIcs18d2/giphy-downsized-large.gif" alt="Snoop Dog!">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Snoop Dog!</h3>
        </div>
      </div>




      <div class="item">
        <img style="width: 100%; max-height: 400px;" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/WZ5tDWAQrUeuk/giphy.gif" alt="Wowzers!">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Wowzers!</h3>
        </div>
      </div>




      <div class="item">
        <img style="width: 100%; max-height: 400px;" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/WZ5tDWAQrUeuk/giphy.gif" alt="wowzers2">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>wowzers2</h3>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfect answer, that fixed it for me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax error is quite obvious and easy to find :: you are invoking your setInterval as follows :

```
     setInterval( "checkServerStatus2( 2020-08-22 20:24:53.520739, 13 )", 10*1000);
```

As we can see your function requires arguments and your first argument is a date&time literal value. But the token is broken at the first (white-space) interval, in which case the JS Engine will be expecting a comma and if comma not encountered, will looking for end of argument list which is exactly what your error reports, a missing ")".

The solution is to either provide an object pointer as an argument or globally accessible a variable name, or a literal string primitive that can be used by the function.

But lets say you are interested in quick test value as we see in your example - your date&time value should also survive the `setInterval` evaluation as a string. So you either escape, or use *single quotes* to preserve the first argument as a string value - like this ::

```
     setInterval( "checkServerStatus2( '2020-08-22 20:24:53.520739', 13 )", 10000);
```

Comment: That was exactly it, thanks for your help.